# What is the purpose of calling the constructor of the object class in Java?

Tags: java, object, constructor, super, default-constructor

Take this simple class...

```
public class Gen
{
    public static void main (String[] Args)
    {
        Gen genny = new Gen();
    }
}
```

[Section 8.8.9](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.9) of the JLS states that "If a class contains no constructor declarations, then a default constructor is **implicitly declared**." It also says that as long as we're not in the `java.lang.object` class, then the "default constructor simply **invokes the superclass constructor with no arguments**."

So because the class `Gen` extends `java.lang.object`, we are forced to call `java.lang.object`'s constructor through `super()` as part of the implicitly-created default constructor.

Likewise...

```
public class Gen extends Object
{   
    public static void main (String[] Args)
    {
        Gen genny = new Gen();
    }
    
    public Gen()
    {
        
    }
}
```

Even if we explicitly declare a constructor for `Gen`, [Section 8.8.7](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.7) of the JLS mandates that "if a constructor body does not begin with an explicit constructor invocation and the constructor being declared is not part of the primordial class `Object`, then the constructor body implicitly **begins with a superclass constructor invocation "super()**;", an invocation of the constructor of its direct superclass that takes no arguments."

So once again, Java is going above and beyond to get us to call `java.lang.object`'s constructor through `super()`. But `java.lang.object`'s constructor literally has an [**empty body**](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/522b65743ca10fcba0a27d25b8fa11319999e228/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/Object.java). It doesn't do anything. A constructor has actual purpose only 1) if you write it such that it initializes a class' instance variables or 2) if it directly/indirectly calls its superclass(es)'s constructors to initialize *their* instance variables. `java.lang.object`'s constructor does neither of these things because it 1) has no instance variables and 2) is the root of the inheritance hierarchy. So it's a pointless constructor. And now, in our class `Gen`, we are being **pointlessly forced to call a pointless constructor**.

Why do this? Why can't the Java people just say "right, if the class is a direct subclass of `java.lang.object` then we won't implicitly define a constructor and neither will we implicitly call `super()` if a constructor explicitly exists." Honestly, why even have a constructor for `java.lang.object` in the first place if it's gonna be empty?

Comment: Because consistency, I guess. Why should I have to check whether a class has an empty constructor *and* is a direct child of `Object` to know how I instantiate it when I can simply call `new Gen()` and not care about the constructor's implementation?

Comment: Your proposed solution sounds more complicated to me. The current situation in Java is "constructors are always called for everything in the inheritance hierarchy", and that's the end of it. If some of those do nothing, then fine. Your proposed solution is "constructors are called except in situations A, B, and C which occur when D, E, or F happen" and involves doing a lot of ad hoc conditional checks against different classes.

Comment: "*But java.lang.object's constructor literally has an empty body*" You'll also note that it's annotated with `@IntrinsicCandidate`. "*A method is intrinsified if the HotSpot VM replaces the annotated method with hand-written assembly and/or hand-written compiler IR -- a compiler intrinsic -- to improve performance."* [source](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/jdk/internal/vm/annotation/IntrinsicCandidate.java)

Comment: And regarding the *why* — because it was designed that way. Java uses this object-oriented model where each class always has a parent (except for `Object`, of course), and since a class instance is initialized through the constructor, all super constructors should be called. And yes, the language designers have set some defaults (implicit no-args constructor and implicit call to `super()`) because this was the least confusing.

Comment: @Michael Yes, that is correct, I mixed up inheritance (`extends`) and calling constructors. I simply couldn't imagine inheritance without actually calling parent constructors. But in theory, it could exist.

Comment: @Michael Interesting...so it's not purely for the sake of consistency like others have said. There's something actually going on at a lower level. I think this is the best explanation, but alas I cannot mark it so

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, it is NOT necessary to write this:

```
 public class Gen extends Object {
```

If a class doesn't explicitly have some other class as its direct superclass, then it *implicitly* extends `Object`.  There is not need to tell the compiler that.

---

Yes ... all classes (apart from `Object`) constructors will call a constructor of their superclass.  Even if the superclass is `Object`.

But it doesn't matter to the programmer.  As the spec says, if the constructor to be called is a no-args constructor, then you don't need an explicit `super` call.  The compiler injects a missing `super()` call for you if you don't include one.

Yes ... the `Object` constructor has an empty body in all Java implementations I have come across.

But I don't think that the JLS mandates that.

The JLS section on how objects are created states that the constructor will be called.

But it doesn't say that the compilers can't optimize away the call to the `Object()` constructor.  And that is what they do.  (The bytecode compiler is required to emit instructions for the call by JVM spec, but the JIT compiler can and will optimize it away.)

Why do they specify it in these terms?

- Primarily because the spec is easier to understand and the language is easier to use if there are fewer special cases in the Java syntax and semantics.

  *"You can't have a `super()` class if the superclass is `Object`"* would be a special case.  But this complexity is not needed to make the language work, and it certainly doesn't help programmers if you *force* them to leave out a `super()` call in this context.
- In addition, the current way permits a Java implementation to have a non-empty `Object()` constructor, if there was a good reason for doing that.  (But I doubt that that was serious consideration when they designed Java.)

---

Either way, this is the way that Java has been since before Java 1.0, and they won't change it now.  The current way doesn't actually cause any problems, or add any appreciable overheads.

Comment: "*I can't recall if the bytecode compiler is required by the JVM*" I tried it before seeing your answer. javac from 17 emits this: 
`invokespecial #1 // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V` (not to say that implies that it's required, but you'd assume they wouldn't bother to emit it if it weren't)

Comment: So, it is apparently required.  (You can look it up in the JVM spec if you want to.)  But it doesn't change what I am saying.